# CodeIgniter session set_flashdata not working

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-2

I've try to use `$this->session->set_flashdata('success')` and it's not working after redirect to another function. Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url','form');
        $this->load->library(array('session','template','form_validation');
    }
}

/* My another function for form_validation and etc */

public function login(){
    $this->set_login_rules();
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        /* inserting data to database */
        $this->session->set_flashdata('welcome');
        redirect('home/welcome');
    }
    $this->template->display('home');
}

public function welcome(){
    if($this->session->flashdata('welcome') !== FALSE){
        echo "<script>alert('Flashdata Success! Welcome!</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Flashdata Failed! Go Away!');</script>";
    }
}
```

when I run the program, it shows alert `Flashdata Failed! Go Away!`
but the login data that I want to insert to database is added into the table.
one more thing, sometimes the `flashdata` is working. From 10 tries, 8-9 tries if show `Flashdata Failed! Go Away!`.
Can anybody tell me why this happend? And how can I fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to give some value to it, so:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('welcome');
```

should be:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('welcome', true);
```

or you can use the full message for example:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('welcome', 'Successfully logged in');
```

etc...

See more info about flashdata here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I've try to add `$message` into it, and still show `Flashdata Failed! Go Away!`. I create the code like this: `$message = 'Welcome to my site!'` and the flashdata is like this: `$this->session->setflashdata('welcome',$message)`
In my `welcome()` I try to echo the flash data like this: `echo $this->sesion->flashdata('welcome');` and it show nothing.

Comment: Could it be that you're redirecting to the welcome page from the view itself without going through validation? What happens when validation fails? You never specified that.

Comment: actually I still have some code bellow the `login()` form_validation->run() code.. If the form_validation failed, I open the home page using this code: `$this->template->display('home')`.
check my update.

Comment: Try putting that into an `else` condition there, or exit after the redirect command, because sometimes another line or two of code is read after the redirect, so it's always a good thing to stop the execution right after it in case there's more code... It could also explain the randomness.

Answer (score 0):

From the Codeigniter documentation:

```
CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared.
```

Your problem might be that when you redirect, the process takes more than one request, that clearing your flashdata.

Use regular session or query parameter.